# verilog testbench component instantiate using generate

Tags: unit-testing, for-loop, verilog, simulation

I'm new to verilog and learning.  I have a testbench questions.
Suppose in Verilog testbench I have 8 instances of a module.
Is there a way to instantiate them in the testbench using a generate loop like a module can be declared in the HDL part of the code. For example

```
module my_test_bench;
reg one_r;
reg two_r;

wire one_w;
wire two_w;

genvar i;
generate
(for i = 0; i < 8; i=i+1)
begin
   DDR3_module uut[i]( .clk(), .rst(), );
end
endgenerate

initial begin
 ... test stimulus
end

end module
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Use the following syntax:

```
genvar i;
generate
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1) begin
    DDR3_module uut (.clk(clk[i]), .rst(rst[i]));
  end
endgenerate
```

Note that you need vectors for the `clk` and `rst` signals for each instance, such as the following preceding declaration lines:

```
wire [7:0] clk;
wire [7:0] rst;
```

If you want to drive those directly from within your `initial` block however, those need to be `reg`s instead of `wire`s.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that would work.  I was hoping that 8 instances of DDR3 modules would show up in Xilinx ISE toolset.  But in simulation I do see all 8.

Comment: @clicker Sorry, I don't think I understand what you are trying to say - If you *are* seeing all 8 in the simulation, what is the problem? I don't know much about ISE, so maybe I am missing something? If that is the case, I recommend updating your question accordingly (add ISE tag and explanation what exactly you're after). Thanks.